# How do I permanently remove a checkout and shopping cart module Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

***How do I permanently remove a checkout and  shopping cart module Magneto 2?  give me solution............***

Comment: why are you removing the checkout and shopping cart module?.let me know any reason.

Comment: My client does not want ecommerce functionality, but he is big admirer of Magento ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can not and should not disable or remove checkout and cart modules. Magento is an e-commerce platform if your client just want to show their products than they should move on CMS based platforms which is lighter then magento.

You can and should advise your client to move on to lighter platform if they want to just show their product and not to sell them.

Answer (score 1):

Permanently removing the default checkout and shopping cart modules in Magento 2 is not recommended due to their dependencies on other modules, which may lead to errors.

Instead, if you wish to disable the default checkout, you can achieve this by navigating to **Admin > System > Configuration > SALES > Checkout > Checkout Options**, and setting "Enable Onepage Checkout" to "No." This will effectively disable the default checkout without permanently removing the modules, ensuring a smoother operation.

It's important to note that the standard practice is to disable rather than remove these modules.

**With this setting customer can still be able to checkout**